# C++ - How can we call a class without calling its attributes?

Tags: c++, class

I need to implement the class `Multiplier` for a school exercise, but I do not understand how the teacher was able to call `prod()` without calling its inputs.

The goal of the code is to read a sequence of integers until the product of their absolute values is greater than 200.

Can somebody help me understanding please?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    Product mult(200); 
    cout << "Enter numbers: " << endl;
    do{
      cin >> mult;
    } while(!mult.exceed_limit()); 

    cout << "The absolute values product is " << mult() << " . " << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the class definition of `Multiplier`? What you describe is possible by overloading the  `()` operator.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What is `Multiplier`? Any secret magic will be in the class.

Comment: Presumably the class has overloaded some operators, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Assumedly this code comes with a `#include "Multiplier.h"` and the actual `Multiplier.h` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Multiplier prod(100);` - `Multiplier` must have defined a constructor that takes an integer as input, eg:

```
class Multiplier
{
...
public:
    Multiplier(int value);
...
};
```

`cin >> prod` - `Multiplier` must have overloaded `operator>>` for input, eg:

```
class Multiplier
{
...
};

istream& operator>>(istream&, Multiplier&);
```

`prod.limit_exceeded()` - `Multiplier` must have defined a member `limit_exceeded()` method, eg:

```
class Multiplier
{
...
public:
    bool limit_exceeded() const;
...
};
```

`cout << prod()` - `Multiplier` must have overloaded `operator()` (and the return value is then streamed to `cout` via `operator<<`), eg:

```
class Multiplier
{
...
public:
    int operator()() const;
...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A class can implement the "call" operation by overloading the `operator()` member function.

For example

```
class MyType {
public:
  void operator()(int param) const {
    std::cout << "MyType(int) called with: " << param << "\n";
  }

  void operator()() const {
    std::cout << "MyType() called\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  MyType  instance;

  instance(12);
  instance();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very much ! What about the "cin >> prod" ? Is prod another variable or does it come from the class object ?

Comment: "_`cin >> prod`_" probably uses an overload like `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Multiplier&);`

Comment: `cin >> prod` is an entirely different matter. You may want to search for "overloading operator>> for istream"

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators for examples of overloading operator>>

Answer (score 1):

Lets see what we need

```
int main()
{
    Multiplier prod(3);
```

A constructor. The parameter is probably the number of factors to be multiplied.

```
    std::cout << "Enter numbers: " << std::endl;
    do{
      std::cin >> prod;
```

A way to "input" the factors.

```
    } while(!prod.limit_exceeded());
```

A method to see if the entered factors equals the number of desired factors.

```
    std::cout << "The product of the absolute values is " << prod() << " . " << std::endl;
```

A call operator that returns the resulting product.

```
    return 0; 
}
```

So lets do that:

```
struct Multiplier {
    Multiplier(size_t n) : max_factors(n),num_factors(0),product(1) {}
    size_t max_factors;
    size_t num_factors;
    double product;
    double operator()() const { return product;}
    bool limit_exceeded() const { return max_factors <= num_factors;}
};
```

Constructor takes number of factors, `product` holds the result, `operator()` returns the result and `limit_exceeded()` checks if all factors have been entered. Finally, a an overload for `operator>>` to read the factors:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Multiplier& m){
    double x;
    if (in >> x) {
        m.product *= x;
        ++m.num_factors;
    }
    return in;
}
```

It is a bit uncommon for `std::cin >> prod;` to not read `prod` but instead to modify `prod`, but thats fine.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/V852Cp)

Comment: Minor nitpick: `if(in >> x) { m.product *= x; ++m.num_factors; }` to avoid UB if it fails.

Comment: @Tedlyngmo no danger of UB, since C++11 `std::cin` will set `x` to `0` when input fails

Comment: @TedLyngmo um actually I dont find it anymore in the reference, so I rather "fix" it

Comment: Yeah, if they have been wobbly about what to do in those situations it's probably best to be safe.

Comment: @TedLyngmo found it again, its here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: @TedLyngmo btw even before c++11 it was a "mild" form of UB, because no way the compiler can know that input fails, so practically the worst that can happen is to get a garbage value, though that doesnt make it less illegal according to the standard